# Failure to get token from Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM application using Identity for authentication that was working fine on Friday. Last night I went to make changes and both the application running in Azure and running locally on my machine began presenting an exception after startup. Nothing has changed in the environment or the code base between everything working fine and now.

The app runs, redirects to the login page, the get is processed fine on the server but throws an exception on the first line of markup in the .cshtml file (assuming because it is failing to encrypt the content at that point):

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
> Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, string additionalMessage)
>
> AggregateException: Multiple exceptions were encountered while
> attempting to authenticate. (EnvironmentCredential authentication
> unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the
> troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot)
> (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple
> attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.)
> (Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\lybeojxv.4oe\TokenService\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe"
> has failed with unexpected error: TS003: Error, TS004: Unable to get
> access token. 'AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity
> provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and
> cannot access the application
> '{IDREDACTED}'(Visual Studio) in that tenant.
> The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
> Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory
> user account. Trace ID: {IDREDACTED}
> Correlation ID: {IDREDACTED} Timestamp:
> 2021-12-20 19:46:59Z'.) (Stored credentials not found. Need to
> authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting
> guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot)
> (Azure CLI not installed) (PowerShell is not installed.)
> Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception
> ex, string additionalMessage)
>
> CredentialUnavailableException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to
> retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the
> troubleshooting guide for more information.
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
>
> - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
>   more information.
>   https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
> - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
> - Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\lybeojxv.4oe\TokenService\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe"
>   has failed with unexpected error: TS003: Error, TS004: Unable to get
>   access token. 'AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity
>   provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and
>   cannot access the application
>   '{IDREDACTED}'(Visual Studio) in that tenant.
>   The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
>   Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory
>   user account. Trace ID: {IDREDACTED}
>   Correlation ID: {IDREDACTED} Timestamp:
>   2021-12-20 19:46:59Z'.
> - Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
>   https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot
> - Azure CLI not installed
> - PowerShell is not installed. Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[]
>   sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, bool async,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the
> provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[]
> plaintext)

I can't find anything in the related documentation and troubleshooting guides that seem to be relevant to my setup and issue. And I feel like I have to be missing something simple like an expiration or change of some credentials but I can't find anything that would appear to be the culprit, and not a single part of the codebase was changed, nor was the Azure environment touched at all by anyone from the time I know it was functional to when this began.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whelp, after pulling my hair out for 2 days, I was able to resolve this by installing the Azure CLI on my machine and running the "az login" command from a PowerShell window. That's all. Hopefully this saves someone else a lot of time.

Comment: Worked for me in `2023` I am using `Rider` though !