# Azure storage account token expired error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0, credentials, azure-storage-account

I  have problem with accesss to azure storage accounts.
In my app i use multiple queues from storage accounts. I need to call QueueClient.GetProperties() method every 30 sec for each queue. The problem is that randomly i got token timeout exception :

> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Asal\TokenService\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe" has failed to get access token in 30 seconds.'

To establish connection with account storage im using VisualStudioCredential
I arleady try to use DefaultAzureCredential, but effect is the same.

On storage account i have roles (IAM):

- Storage Queue Data Contributor
- Storage Account Contributor

Is there any solution for this problem or any way to debugg this error?

Is it possible to cache existing token to avoid sending request every time interval?

**Code Update**

```
static Dictionary<string, QueueClient> _queueStorageClient = new 
Dictionary<string, QueueClient>();

public static QueueClient QueueStorage(string? QueueName, string? accountName = null)
{

    if (!_queueStorageClient.TryGetValue(QueueName, out QueueClient? queueStorageClient))
    {
        var url="***";
        var queueStorageClient = new QueueClient(uri, new VisualStudioCredential());
        _queueStorageClient.TryAdd(QueueName, queueStorageClient);

    }
 return queueStorageClient;
}
```

Timer method code:

```
System.Timers.Timer? timer= null;

timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 30000;
timer.Elapsed += async (sender, arguments) => await Handler_OnTimer(sender, arguments, queueName);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

handler:

```
public static async Task Handler_OnTimer(Object? source, 

System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, string queueName)
    {
      ...
        QueueProperties queueProperities = await QueueStorage(queueName).GetPropertiesAsync();
...
}
```

I noticed that on the first request for each queue I can get properties without token exception. The problem occurs from the next request on random queue

Comment: Have you checked the settings in case you need to refresh the credentials? Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication.

Comment: Yes, that  was the first thing that i tried.

Comment: I noticed that `var queueStorageClient = new QueueClient(uri, new VisualStudioCredential());` will get called every time because you are not populating the cache (`static Dictionary<string, QueueClient> _queueStorageClient = new 
Dictionary<string, QueueClient>();`).

Comment: Sorry i forgot about one line of code. I'm using a static variable instead of the classic cache. the StorageClient queue is initialized only once. I just add a new client to the dictionary when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure storage account token expired error

To solve this issue, you can use **`DefaultAzurecredential`** with login using **`az login`** in your terminal.

You can achieve this by going to *View -> terminal -> type az login and login with your Microsoft account*. Also, please check if your identity package is in the correct updated version.

Regarding your question about caching the existing token to avoid sending a request every time interval, you can use the below code to get the properties of queue storage with **`DefaultAzurecredential`** using .NET:

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;


public class QueueClientManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, QueueClient> _queueStorageClients = new Dictionary<string, QueueClient>();
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static QueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_queueStorageClients.TryGetValue(queueName, out var queueClient))
            {
                var queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(new Uri("https://venkat123.queue.core.windows.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
                queueClient = queueServiceClient.GetQueueClient(queueName);
                _queueStorageClients[queueName] = queueClient;
            }
            return queueClient;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static async Task Handler_OnTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, string queueName)
    {
            var queueClient = QueueClientManager.GetQueueClient(queueName);
            var queueProperties = await queueClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queueName}' Properties: Approximate message count: {queueProperties.Value.ApproximateMessagesCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queueName}' Metadata:");
            foreach (var s in queueProperties.Value.Metadata)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"{s.Key}: {s.Value}");
            }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string queueName = "queue25";
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 30000; // 30 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, arguments) => await Handler_OnTimer(sender, arguments, queueName);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Monitoring queue '{queueName}' every 30 seconds. Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Monitoring queue 'queue25' every 30 seconds. Press Enter to exit...
Queue 'queue25' Properties: Approximate message count: 1
Queue 'queue25' Metadata:
hi: hello
```

[image]

**Reference:**

- [DefaultAzureCredential Class (Azure.Identity) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet)
- [Failure to get token from Azure Key Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427351/failure-to-get-token-from-azure-key-vault) by Chris Searles.

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. But I just noticed that on the first request for each queue I can get a token without exception. The problem occurs from the next request

Comment: @ProgShiled var queueStorageClient = new QueueClient(uri, new VisualStudioCredential());  (static Dictionary<string, QueueClient> _queueStorageClient = new  Dictionary<string, QueueClient>();) yep i agree with gaurav mantri comment it will get called every time because you are not populating the cache.